# iOS : subclassing UINavigationBar for custom title view

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I've subclassed `UINavigationBar`, I wanted to have a `UIView` contains UIImageView + UILabel inside it, I'm able to achieve it by setting `titleView` property. But, what I want to know is whether its possible to add it inside subclass directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way add one UIView on Navigationbar and then add any component on that so it is easy to manage those component because if you add component on left button right button and title label it not that much flexible to customise (i.e. if you added any component on titleLabel you can set that component frame only equal or less that title label. but if you add on UIView on Navigation bar then you can customise all components easily)

I hope it will help you.